# <?php echo $option['price']; ?> it's not working on the cart.tpl - Opencart 2.2

Tags: opencart2.x

[This is what I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IAqHk.png)

`<?php echo $option['price']; ?>` it's not working on the cart.tpl - Opencart 2.2

```
<td class="text-left"><a href="<?php echo $product['href']; ?>"><?php echo $product['name']; ?></a> 
              <?php if (!$product['stock']) { ?>
              <span class="text-danger">***</span>
              <?php } ?>
              <?php if ($product['option']) { ?> 
              <?php foreach ($product['option'] as $option) { ?>
              <br />
              <small><?php echo $option['name']; ?>: 
                  <?php echo $option['value']; ?> - Price 
                  <?php echo $option['price']; ?>
                  </small> 
              <?php } ?>
              <?php } ?>
              <?php if ($product['reward']) { ?>
              <br />
              <small><?php echo $product['reward']; ?></small>
              <?php } ?>
              <?php if ($product['recurring']) { ?>
              <br />
              <span class="label label-info"><?php echo $text_recurring_item; ?></span> <small><?php echo $product['recurring']; ?></small>
              <?php } ?></td>
```

Answer (score 0):

Below solution will be very helpful for you.

```
<?php echo $option['price']; ?>
```

instead of

```
<?php echo isset($option['price']); ?>
```

i think it's solved and not any error found.

```
<td class="text-left"><a href="<?php echo $product['href']; ?>"><?php echo $product['name']; ?></a> 
              <?php if (!$product['stock']) { ?>
              <span class="text-danger">***</span>
              <?php } ?>
              <?php if ($product['option']) { ?> 
              <?php foreach ($product['option'] as $option) { ?>
              <br />
              <small><?php echo $option['name']; ?>: 
                  <?php echo $option['value']; ?> - Price 
                  <?php echo isset($option['price']); ?>
                  </small> 
              <?php } ?>
              <?php } ?>
              <?php if ($product['reward']) { ?>
              <br />
              <small><?php echo $product['reward']; ?></small>
              <?php } ?>
              <?php if ($product['recurring']) { ?>
              <br />
              <span class="label label-info"><?php echo $text_recurring_item; ?></span> <small><?php echo $product['recurring']; ?></small>
              <?php } ?></td>
```